# How to validate files in a folder in server before file request processeced using asp.net core 2.1 midleware

Tags: c#, clickonce, asp.net-core-2.1

We are trying to run ClickOnce file(.application) which are placed in the server through anchor link in asp.net core 2.1, Functionality is working fine but I want to check the user access to that file before it gets opened to him and also wants to write user access logs into the database. I am achieving this using Middleware Invoke method using below code but it is triggering Invoke method twice and inserting duplicate records for each request.

Could anybody help how could solve duplicate database hitting?

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IConfiguration iconfiguration, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {

        userName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
        {
            userName = userName.ToLower();
        }
        OracleDbAppstoreContext dbContext = new OracleDbAppstoreContext(iconfiguration, env);
        try
        {
            bool isAuthenticated = false;
            string pack_id = "";
            environment = Convert.ToString(iconfiguration["Environment"]);
            string reqPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
            if (reqPath.Count() > 0 && reqPath.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                reqPath = reqPath.Substring(1, reqPath.Length - 1);
                if (reqPath.Split("/").Count() > 2)
                {
                    pack_id = reqPath.Split("/")[1];
                }

            }

            isAuthenticated = SiteAccessHelper.IsAdmin(Convert.ToString(iconfiguration["ADGroup"]).ToUpper(), Convert.ToString(iconfiguration["Domain_Name"]).ToUpper(), userName, iconfiguration, httpContextAccessor);

            if (isAuthenticated == false)
            {

                isAuthenticated = dbContext.APS_BOTS_PACKAGES.UserAccessForPackage(pack_id, userName, httpContextAccessor);

            }


            if (isAuthenticated == true)
            {

                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;


                // context.Response.Redirect(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, reqPath));
                //await _next(context);
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                await context.Response.SendFileAsync(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, reqPath));

            }
            else
            {

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are not the authorized person to access this link");

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dbContext.APS_Excpetion_Logging.SendErrorToText(ex, "MyHandlerMiddleware/Invoke");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("There is an unhandled exception, please reachout to CT RPA Team");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: add breakpoint  on your code then check stacktrace

Comment: I have checked, it is not giving any exception, the Invoke method is being called twice, so duplicate logs are getting